# Setting Double Array Values

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix, typeerror

I'm getting an error when I'm trying to assign values to an empty 2D array.

It says `Cannot set property '0' of undefined`.

Why is this and how can I fix it so that I can assign values from a 2D array to a new empty 2D array?

```
var array = await data;
array = JSON.parse(array);

var activeArray = new Array();
var inactiveArray = new Array();

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    if (array[i][2] == "Active")
    {
        activeArray[i][0] = array[i][0];
        activeArray[i][1] = array[i][1];
        activeArray[i][2] = array[i][2];
    }
    else
    {
        inactiveArray[i][0] = array[i][0];
        inactiveArray[i][1] = array[i][1];
        inactiveArray[i][2] = array[i][2];
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe if you show you array values?

Comment: activeArray[i] is a valid field but you didn‘t define a value for it (in your case it needs to be another array). Before accessing the 2nd dimension you need to set activeArray[i] = new Array()

Comment: Thanks, just fixed it.

Comment: "Edit: It was because the constructor only creates one-dimensional arrays. This has been fixed. Thanks for the help." - mention this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This effectively solved my problem.

```
    var array = await data;
    array = JSON.parse(array);

    var activeArray = new Array();
    var inactiveArray = new Array();
    var activeArrayCounter = 0;
    var inactiveArrayCounter = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        if (array[i][2] == "Active")
        {
            activeArray[activeArrayCounter] = new Array();
            activeArray[activeArrayCounter][0] = array[i][0];
            activeArray[activeArrayCounter][1] = array[i][1];
            activeArray[activeArrayCounter][2] = array[i][2];
            activeArrayCounter++;
        }
        else
        {
            inactiveArray[inactiveArrayCounter] = new Array();
            inactiveArray[inactiveArrayCounter][0] = array[i][0];
            inactiveArray[inactiveArrayCounter][1] = array[i][1];
            inactiveArray[inactiveArrayCounter][2] = array[i][2];
            inactiveArrayCounter++;
        }
    }
```